# How do I run a local command with fabric 2?

Tags: python, fabric

I want to use Fabric and run a command on local, without having to establish any additional connections.

How do I do this in **fabric 2**? ... [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.3/api/connection.html?highlight=local) seems to miss to give any example.

Answer (score 9):

The design decision to drop the `local` command in Fabric 2 makes this more difficult, but I was able to simulate it by using `Context` from Invoke instead of `Connection`:

```
from fabric import Connection
from invoke.context import Context

@task
def hostname(c):
    c.run('hostname')

@task
def test(c):
    conn = Connection('user@host')
    hostname(conn)
    local_ctx = Context(c.config)  # can be passed into @task;
                                   # Connection is a subclass of Context
    hostname(local_ctx)
```

Comment: You could also do `import from invoke run as local` and use as `local('ls -lsha')`

Comment: ^ this worked for me in the way `local` used to work in fabric 1:    the correct import syntax though is:  `from invoke import run as local`

Answer (score 4):

After several different attemps and spending lots of time I found this elegant solution for starting a server (pty=True) and run local commands.

**fabfile.py**

```
from fabric import task

@task
def env_test(c):
    c.run("env", replace_env=False)

@task
def go(c):
    c.run("manage.py runserver", replace_env=False, pty=True)
```

*Please be aware again, these two commands are only meant for local development tasks!*

**Further Reading:** [Fabric2 Connections](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/api/connection.html?highlight=Operations#fabric.connection.Connection), [Upgrading from 1.x](http://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html#upgrading-from-1-x)

Answer (score 3):

run, sudo, and local are done the same:

```
from fabric import Connection                                                                                  

cn = Connection('scott@104.131.61.12')    # presumes ssh keys were exchanged                                        

cn.run('ls -al')     # assuming ssh to linux server - as scott                  
cn.sudo('whoami')    # as root                                                  
cn.local('echo ---------- now from local')                                      
cn.local('dir /w')   # assuming client is windows
```

Comment: beware, connection.local does not get all env variables. https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1744

Answer (score 2):

I am adding @TheRealChx101's comment as an answer because I ran into troubles with `Connection.local`.
Not all environment variables got into the pty, so some of my scripts did not work properly.

With the `import from invoke run as local` stanza (Invoke's local instead of Fabric's), everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from fabric import task
from invoke import run as local
@task(default=True)
def testwxmsg(c):
    local("pytest --reuse-db --no-migrations tests/weixin/test_release_accrual.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the answer by @phoibos, but I wanted to show that `@task` is not needed.

```
import sys
from fabric import Connection
from invoke.context import Context

target_host=sys.argv[1]

if target_host == 'localhost':
    ctx = Context()
else:
    ctx = Connection(target_host)

ctx.run('hostname', echo=False, hide=None)

if isinstance(ctx, Connection):
    ctx.close()
```

Local:

```
> python demo.py localhost
MyComputerName
```

Remote:

```
> python demo.py demo.example.com
demo.example.com
```